# Legends with Arabic text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add the coordinate of [Tall al Kabir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_al_Kabir) and other Arabic locations to a map. How do I add Arabic text to my map legend?

This is the Arabic text: الكبير

This is the unicode: \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0628\u064a\u0631

How do I make that unicode appear as Arabic text?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Matplotlib supports unicode and you will find all required characters in the unicode tables.

Comment: @cel Thanks! Found unicode converters here http://mylanguages.org/converter.php and here https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter